# Randomly Floating PWM signal

Tags: digital-logic, pcb-design, pwm, microprocessor, floating

I am having trouble with a randomly floating digital signal. Transmission is between a microprocessor and a CPLD unit and is used to run a  half bridge. Measurement was taken after the output resistor of the processor and appeared after about 5 to 50min of running time for multiple times. Do you have any idea what could have caused this?
From my point of view a mechanical loose connection didnt cause this, because its first to fast and also the system does not respond to mechanical forces.

Here you can see the problem (green signal), red is the other signal sent towards the CPLD. Blue can be ignored, this was the error output by the CPLD because of the signal received.[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility that something in the MCU code is switching your PWM output signal from an output to an input?

Comment: I have had this before. I assume green is coming from the CPLD? Try to add a flipflop at the output, registering green.

Comment: It looks like it could be +ve ground shift from a flyback effect on a switch causing a negative differential slope,  but without details of your grounds + physical layout, power and logical interface, that’s a SWAG

Comment: They are both from the MCU to the CPLD. CPLD is used to check the dead times in between the two incoming signals. What really is bringing questions that it appears only after some time running.

Software wise there is no change made in the code. Also other boards are just running fine with the same code. So I dont think the issue is coming from there.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 the path of the green signal is slightly longer but not really long. Ground is connected quite well, I do have two ground planes in the multilayer pcb here with vias nearby

Comment: Any undefined or unexpected interrupts fire during that time?

Comment: Do you mean interrupt in software or in the surrounding of the system? As far as I can see nothing special from software side. We are driving a motor with this setup and it was running without any changes until the point of error. So no special changes. Only point I can see is that with longer running times the error becomes less common. But I could increase the times of reproducing by adding better cooling, so I cant say for sure that it is thermal.

Comment: It's possible there's some mechanical issue. The different time scales to recover are suggestive of something non-electronic. Inspect soldering on the relevant pin, if possible, and try heating/cooling the board and MCU.

Comment: What could cause a 10us analog glitch ?  Without details it’s hard to analyze